# Condições no SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Olá, estou com uma dúvida no SQL.
No sistema da empresa existem vários produtos cadastrados, e esses produtos tem unidade de venda diferente, ou seja, alguns são vendidos por Pacote, Caixa, Unidade e etc...
Todo produto é vendido por UNIDADE = 1, porém existem produtos que quando é vendido em outra unidade de venda, ocorre uma redução no preço dele para '0.98', exemplo:
Produto Parafuso:

Unidade de Venda - fator_preço

UN(Unidade) -            1

CX(Caixa) -              1

PT(Pacote) - 0.98

Eu queria fazer um seguinte, se as unidades de venda tivessem o fator preço tudo '1', então iria ignorar este produto...
Porém se alguma unidade de venda for igual a '0.98' eu pego o '0.98' + as outras unidades de venda com os valores.
No exemplo do parafuso:
Como Existe uma unidade de Venda que tem o preço '0.98'(PT), eu pegaria o '1'(CX) e o '1'(UN) também...
Mas se caso o fator preço de todas as unidades de venda desse produto fosse '1' então eu ignorava o mesmo...

Eu tentei este Código:

```
SELECT 
produto.cd_prod,
produto.descricao,
unid_prod.qtde_unid,
unid_prod.fator_preco,
unid_vda
FROM 
produto,
unid_prod
WHERE
unid_prod.cd_prod = produto.cd_prod
AND unid_prod.fator_preco IN('0.9800', '1')
```

Porém nesta query o banco trás os dados dos 2 sem filtragem, mesmo que o produto não tenha 0.9800 ele trás...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando como exemplo as tabelas:

```
produto                       unid_prod

cd_prod descricao             cd_prod fator_preco unid_vda
------- ------------          ------- ----------- --------
p1      Produto 1             p1      1           CX
p2      Produto 2             p1      1           UN
p3      Produto 3             p2      0.98        PT
                              p2      1           UN
                              p3      1           UN
                              p3      0.98        PT
```

Você deseja montar uma query que retorne as informações dos produtos `p2` e `p3`, porque possuem pelo menos um `fator_preco = 0.98`, e não retorne o produto `p1` porque não contempla essa condição.

O resultado desejado seria o seguinte:

```
cd_prod descricao    fator_preco unid_vda
------- ------------ ----------- --------
p2      Produto 2    0.98        PT
p2      Produto 2    1           UN
p3      Produto 3    1           UN
p3      Produto 3    0.98        PT
```

Uma forma de se conseguir esse resultado seria fazer um `JOIN` entre as tabelas `produto` e `unid_prod` colocando uma subquery na cláusula `WHERE` para verificar se o produto possui pelos menos um registro em `unid_prod` que tenha `fator_preco = '0.9800'`.

A query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT produto.cd_prod,
       produto.descricao,
       unid_prod.qtde_unid,
       unid_prod.fator_preco,
       unid_vda
  FROM produto
  JOIN unid_prod ON unid_prod.cd_prod = produto.cd_prod
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT *
                FROM unid_prod as un
               WHERE un.cd_prod = produto.cd_prod
                 AND un.fator_preco = '0.9800')
```

Comment: poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/262497/edit) sua resposta e colocar um explicação ? Seria muito bom para o **AP** e para futuros usuários que tiverem o mesmo problema, saber aonde é que esta o **erro**.

Comment: @wmsouza, adicionei uma explicação à resposta. Obrigado por sua sugestão.

Answer (score 0):

Para trazer todos os produtos e unidade produtos caso *exista* alguma unidade 0,98, basta usar a cláusula **EXISTS** através de uma sub consulta:

```
SELECT produto.cd_prod, produto.descricao, unid_prod.qtde_unid, unid_prod.fator_preco, unid_prod.unid_vda 
FROM produto, unid_prod 
WHERE unid_prod.cd_prod = produto.cd_prod 
AND EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1 FROM unid_prod subUnid 
    WHERE subUnid.cd_prod produto.cd_prod AND subUnid.fator_preco = '0.9800' )
```